# Lost power during XP CheckDisk - Can't See Partition Now

Tags: windows-xp, boot, partition

I initiated a reboot to perform a disk check, and during the check I lost power to the machine. Now it doesn't boot.

I ran disk utilities on the HDD and everything checks out, but windows won't boot.

The drive has 2 paritions (one is a manufacturer repair drive), and the repair parition is perfectly fine (accessible, etc.), but the OS parition seems to be shot.

I pulled the drive, and plugged it into another machine, which recognizes it, assignes it a drive letter, but I can't access any files on the drive or get any information about it (size, gb used/free, etc.)

I tried doing a windows repair, but it doesn't detect any installations of windows and simply wants to install over the parition via a reformat.

I realize I'm probably up a creek without a paddle on the partition, but I thought I'd reach out and see if anyone had a way to recover data from the drive before I call it a loss and reformat...

Are there any tools available to me to recover data?

Also, why would power loss during a disk check cause the parition to blow out? I've never seen this happen before; in the past I've been able to run a windows repair and recover the installation.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried running chkdsk from the installation CD in repair mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to resolve:

- I used "Partition Recovery" to get into the corrupted partition
- I made a copy of all data using a scratch drive
- Ran the Recovery tool that came with the machine (HP Restore) to reinstall OS
- Repopulated data onto fresh intstall from scratch drive
- Reinstalled Programs
- Configured backups for the machine

User was back online after that. No data loss, only programs lost client didn't know/want installed anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:[SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page)

If it's not working and no data probably the metadata are corrupt/gone...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a program called testdisk. It's opensource and does a good job to deal with different filesystem partitions. It helped me many times.